# Logic assigment: prove (A->C) v (A->D) therefore A->CvD

Tags: logic

just started logic, and I cannot seem to know know to solve this assigment.
I've tried this:

[image: I've tried this]

I suspect I cannot break the disjunction on P, only with A hypotesis. How should I split it?

Thank you

Comment: $A\implies C $ is equivalent with $\neg A\ lor C$ so we get $(\neg A\lor C ) \lor (\neg A\lor D)$ hence $\neg A \lor (C\lor D)$ so $A\implies (C\lor D)$

Comment: The fist step is to apply Disjunction-elim to the premise and then the two sub-proofs assuming A.

Comment: @HassanJolany - there is no math formula processor on PhilSE.

Comment: I'll look at your suggestions. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve each of the cases into the term you want to proof to be able to use a disjunction elimination, like so:
[image]

Comment: I also tried to solve the subproof A->C, etc. but it didn't occur to me to nest another subproof for that. Now it looks so simple.
Thanks for the complete answer. I know the socratic method is usually best to get a good understanding, but in my case I needed this step-by-step guide.